# Defining JQuery arrays for multiple products against 'page ids'

Tags: jquery, arrays

We are currently looking to create an array in which we can separately define the 'page IDs' (automatically created by the platform) and which products they apply to. I need the arrays to be flattened in order for the first IF statement to work which checks if the current page ID matches ANY of the defined arrays.

I then need the second IF statement to check the current page ID against the individual array indexes (aka 'product1'). If it matches with an array value that exists for that particular product, then show something applicable to that product.

```
var solutions = [];
solutions["product1"] = [46, 47, 48, 49];
solutions["product2"] = [40, 41, 42, 43];
var currentID = pageData.content.category.id; //gets current page ID

$.each(solutions, function (index, val) {
 if ((pageData.content.category.id == val) > -1) {
   /* do something */
 }
 if($.inArray(currentID, solutions[index]) !== -1) {
   /* do something */
 }
});
```

Comment: `solutions` should be an object, not an array. Arrays have numeric indexes, objects have string keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: No need to use jQuery here.

Next: you want the `solutions` to be an object, not an array.  WIth an object you can look up items by key name.

Finally: to check if a variable is equal to a key in an object, one way to do this is to iterate over the keys and then do something when a match is found, like this:

```js
const pageData = {
  content: {
    category:{ id: "product2" }
  }
}
//=================================

const solutions = {
  product1: [46, 47, 48, 49],
  product2: [40, 41, 42, 43]
};

const currentID = pageData.content.category.id; //gets current page ID

Object.keys(solutions).forEach((key) => {
  const val = solutions[key];
  if (currentID === key) {
    console.log(`Current ID: ${key} and the array is: `, val)
  }
});
```

An even simpler way though is to just access that object property directly since we have the ID.  I recommend this way.

```js
const pageData = {
  content: {
    category:{ id: "product2" }
  }
}
//=================================

const solutions = {
  product1: [46, 47, 48, 49],
  product2: [40, 41, 42, 43]
};

const currentID = pageData.content.category.id; //gets current page ID
const currentProduct = solutions[currentID];

console.log(`Current ID: ${currentID} and the array is: `, currentProduct)
```

---

Revising based on new information

```js
const pageData = {
  content: {
    category:{ id: 42 }
  }
}
//=================================

const solutions = {
  product1: [46, 47, 48, 49],
  product2: [40, 41, 42, 43]
};

const currentID = pageData.content.category.id; //gets current page ID

//Object.entries provides an tuple array of object keys as the first item and object values as the second item
//Using .find() we can narrow this down to only give us the one product that contains the matching ID
const match = Object.entries(solutions).find(s=>s[1].includes(currentID));

if(match){
  //If a match is found, the first item in the array will be the product name, or the key of the object
  //If needed, match[1] will give you all the items for the matching product
  console.log(`Current ID: ${currentID}, Current Product: ${match[0]}`)
  console.log(`All items for this product:`, match[1])
} else {
  //If there is no match found, handle that
  console.log(`Unable to locate a product that contains ID ${currentID}`);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but unfortunately this doesn't solve my issue. The ID of the page is always a number, not the name of the product, and there can be multiple numbers that represent one product. So, for example, if I were looking at a page and the ID was 46, I would want the code to be able to identify that the page I'm on is for 'product1'.

Comment: ok, I don't think that was very clear in your original question since there was no sample data provided for what the current ID would be.  Regardless I have updated my answer to work as you have described now.